# Writing a custom Django BaseCommand class that logs the command details

Tags: python, django

I have a a number of management commands in my Django application. I'd like a entry to be logged to one my models, every time a management command is run. The model contains four fields:

- `started` - the time when the command was started.
- `ended` - the time when the command was ended/stopped.
- `success` - a boolean value indicating whether the command ran successfully or not.
- `name` - the name of the command.

I thought the best way to implement this would be write a custom class called `LoggedBaseCommand` which derives from `django.core.management.base.BaseCommand`. My management commands would derive from this class which would contain the simple logging functionality.

I know some bits and pieces on how to implement this but I can't seem to figure out how to glue this together.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: So far so good.  Post your `class LoggedBaseCommand(django.core.management.base.BaseCommand)` code that you have so far.  You only need to override `handle` so it shouldn't be too much code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from commandlog.models import CommandLogEntry
class LoggedBaseCommand(Command):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # 'started' ought to be automatic, 'ended' and 'success' not yet determined.
        c = CommandLogEntry(name = __file__)
        result = "FAIL"
        try:
            result = self.handle_and_log(*args, **options)
        except: 
            pass
        c.success = result
        c.ended = datetime.datetime.now()
        c.save()

    def handle_and_log(self, *args, **options):
        # All of your child classes use this.
```

You might have to fiddle with the `__file__` entry, perhaps using `re`, to strip out paths and terminating '.py', but since every command is predicated on its file name in the hierarchy, this ought to do the trick.  Note that I assume failure, and only record success if the `handle_and_log()` function passes back a success string.  (Changes to suit your needs).  If it throws an exception, failure is recorded.  Again, change to suit your needs (i.e. record the exception string).